# postincrement pointers with arrays

Tags: c, pointers

Cannot understand why value of a[1] is not equal to 10

```
void main()
{
    int a[]={2,1};
    int *ptr=a;
    *ptr++=10; //trying to update a[1]=10
    printf("%d",*ptr);
}
```

Could someone pls explain this?

Comment: Shoudn't it because the pointer get incremented after you make the assignment? Shouldn't you do `*++ptr=10;`?

Comment: since post increment has higher precedence over *,it shud first increment d pointer and denassign 10 to a[1]?

Comment: @haccks yes...sorry it was 10

Comment: All in all, well formed first question, but certainly a duplicate.

Comment: Love any question that results in more light shed on this topic.  +1

Answer (score 5):

Let's take your code, and space it out some:

```
int main() {
    int a[]={2,1};
    int *ptr=a;

    // Validation 
    assert(ptr == &a[0]);

    // Let's now do what *ptr++ = 10 actually does:
    *ptr = 10;
    ptr = ptr + 1;

    // Validation
    assert(ptr == &a[1]);

    // Printing. Note that we are printing a[1], not a[0].
    printf("%d",*ptr);
}
```

It might also be helpful to read a quote from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_incdec). They are discussing the difference between a postfix increment (`ptr++`) and a prefix increment (`++ptr`).

> The returned result of the **postfix** version of the operator is the original operand, with a side-effect being that the operand is incremented/decremented after this result is returned.
>
> The returned result of the **prefix** version of the operator is the incremented/decremented operand.

It sounds like you want to use a prefix increment, not a postfix increment.

Comment: @sharth first increment and den assign

Comment: @user3753605: Perhaps the additional content I've added is useful.

Comment: What would the prefix-increment version of `*ptr++=10; ` look like?

Comment: @ryyker: `*++ptr = 10;`

Comment: @ryyker: Without seeing your code, it will be hard to comment. In general, there is no issue: http://ideone.com/AACN58

Comment: Thanks.  Had it at `++(*ptr)`, which led to `Lvalue required` error.. Nice answer by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Since `++` has higher precedence than unary `*`, `*p++` is going to be grouped as `*(p++)` which means: Dereference the old `ptr` and increment `ptr` by `1` (as long as the original value is used, the increment can happen at any time). `*ptr++=10;` will update `a[0]` to `10`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code commented as execution flows:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a[]={2,1}; //sets a[0]=2, a[1]=1
    int *ptr=a;    //sets *ptr == address of a, or a[0]
    *ptr++=10;     //sets a[0] = 10  (a[1] unchanged)
    printf("%d",*ptr);
    getchar();
}
```

`*ptr++=10;` assigns the value 10 to the address of a[0], *then* increments *ptr *after* that assignment is made.